# MySQL: fix fully duplicate row

Tags: php, mysql

I have table `tags`  and I forget to set `id` column as primary key when created it.

Now I am facing a *duplicate key* problem.

**`tags` table:**

```
id     text
1      man
2      ball
2      ball
2      ball
3      love
3      love
4      heart
4      heart
```

How to remove duplication and keep  and set `id` as the primary key ?

**Expected result:** ( the new required `tags` table)

```
id     text
1      man
2      ball
3      love
4      heart
```

Comment: I want to remove duplication, (not select)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would do, is create a new table, add the key insert the data from the old table, then drop `tags` and rename `temp`

```
/* Make a copy of the database table (including indexes) */
create table tags_tmp like tags;

/* Add the primary key to the table */
alter table tags_tmp add primary key (id);

/* Insert the data from the bad table and ignore any duplicates */
insert ignore into tags_tmp (id, text)
    select id, text from tags;

/* Drop the bad table */
drop table tags;

/* Rename the temporary table to the original name */
rename table tags_tmp to tags;
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the easiest way is to create a temporary table with the data and then reload the data:

```
create temporary table tags_temp as
    select distinct id, text
    from tags;

truncate table tags;

alter table tags add primary key (id);

insert into tags(id, text)
    select id, temp
    from tags_temp;
```

Comment: I receive this error: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'add primary key (id)' at line 1

Comment: @mwafi . . . It needs the table name, oops.

Answer (score 1):

**First, I created your table and inserted data in:**

```
mysql> select * from tags;
+----+-------+
| id | text  |
+----+-------+
|  1 | man   |
|  2 | ball  |
|  2 | ball  |
|  2 | ball  |
|  3 | love  |
|  3 | love  |
|  4 | heart |
|  4 | heart |
+----+-------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

**I backup the distinct entries only:**

```
mysql> create table T as select distinct * from tags;
Query OK, 4 rows affected (0.27 sec)
Records: 4  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
```

**I no longer need the original table, so I drop it from the database:**

```
mysql> drop table tags;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.12 sec)
```

**I rename the previous backup table:**

```
mysql> rename table T to tags;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.08 sec)
```

**Now it is time to add the PRIMARY KEY constraint to our table:**

```
mysql> alter table tags add  primary key(id);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.48 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
```

**Now, let us test if what we did is correct. First, let us display the data:**

```
mysql> select * from tags;
+----+-------+
| id | text  |
+----+-------+
|  1 | man   |
|  2 | ball  |
|  3 | love  |
|  4 | heart |
+----+-------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

**Let's try to add a row with id = 4:**

```
mysql> insert into tags values(4,'proof');
ERROR 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry '4' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

**Conclusion:** what we did is correct.